# .net Core HangFire set Cron time

Tags: cron, hangfire

Hi I gotta work with hangfire cron but I can't understand setting cron time ("***** is everysecond i know")

Also I searched there are some websites about that, but when i set some date i copied and paste anohter site and site says wrong type.

Hangfire makes some easy way to set time like

```
Cron.Daily //work on every day 00.00

Cron.HourInterval
```

I gotta work a function every day 14.00,How can i make it like
`Cron.Daily(14)` or somethning else. Thank you

I'm really unsure. one site can genareta cron and it give this

work every weekday at 14.00

```
0 0 14 ? * MON-FRI *
```

other does not accepts it , it accepts this

```
0 14 * * *
```

Which one works for hangfire

Comment: Or  with the "*****" way , works everyday at 2 pm(14.00)

Comment: 0   14  *   *   *  does it will work in hangFire

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to run the job week days at 2PM,

```
"0 14 * * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI"
"0 14 * * MON-FRI"
"0 14 * * 1,2,3,4,5"
"0 14 * * 1-5"
```

and if you want to do the job daily,

```
"0 14 * * SUN–SAT"
```

[Documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression) on cron expressions used by Hangfire.

**Cron**

Hangfire does have its own internal representation for the Cron Expressions but dont give you as much control like weekdays.. but they are there.

You can create a recurring job with the following syntax using Cron class from `Hangfire.Core`. This recurring job will run every day at 1400 hours.

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("name", () => Test(), Cron.Daily(14));
```

You can also use a variety of other Cron methods available, including, `Weekly(), Monthly(), Yearly` etc. All of these methods' definitions can be [found here](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/3c6d893023d5d7558d6098e80034865004b73786/src/Hangfire.Core/Cron.cs)